# How could I add or "inject" a component from a service to the dom in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

As I can create a component from a service in angular, I want to do it as an alert service and that service has several methods like error () that method would have to add a component to the dom to display the alert, but I don't know how to " inject "or" add "a component of a service to the dom,, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you can do is to create an alert [Module](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules) with a service to be injected and components.
Configure your alerts and templates in regular components inside the module and import it to your app's top module and then inject only the service wherever you want to use it.

Check out [Angular Material Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) I think you'll find it useful.

Comment: But from a service you cannot do that, because the service does not have an html template

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you are trying to achieve? With code will be even better

Comment: Edit the question, it is better understood?, if I don't try to add code